# When using OnevsRest classifier, is it possible to know the accuracy for each classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a OnevsRest classifier.
I have a dataset with 21 classes. I want to know the accuracy for each classifier.

For example:

Accuracy for class1 vs (class2+classx...+ class21)

Accuracy for class2 vs (class3+classx...+ class21)

.

.

.

Accuracy for class21 vs (class1+classx...+ class20)

How can I know that?

```
# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
print(y_score)
```

Comment: Maybe `classifier.coef_` by (n classes x m columns). Or do `for est in classifier.estimators_: accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(X_test))`. Note: you'd have to fit it first, not just fit and get the score all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not supported out of the box and you will need to do it yourself.

Here is some example-code, which i will call a **prototype**, because it's not heavily tested! Keep in mind, that it's hard to compare single-class accuracies and the meta-accuracy (which is based on probability-estimates; in the SVM-case obtained by Platt-scaling).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris_X = iris.data
iris_y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris_X, iris_y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Train classifier
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
    random_state=0))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
print(y_score)

# Get all accuracies
classes = np.unique(y_train)

def get_acc_single(clf, X_test, y_test, class_):
    pos = np.where(y_test == class_)[0]
    neg = np.where(y_test != class_)[0]
    y_trans = np.empty(X_test.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    y_trans[pos] = True
    y_trans[neg] = False
    return clf.score(X_test, y_trans)                    # assumption: acc = default-scorer

for class_index, est in enumerate(classifier.estimators_):
    class_ = classes[class_index]
    print('class ' + str(class_))
    print(get_acc_single(est, X_test, y_test, class_))
```

Output:

```
0.8133333333333334
class 0
1.0
class 1
0.6666666666666666
class 2
0.9733333333333334
```

Comment: And if we use `probability = False`, will the accuracy be okey?